# execution of JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

could you help me understand what's wrong with the code and why the button doesn't work when I click on it. 
I believe that I missed some little part and I can't find it.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Conditions</title>
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script>
        function AgeCh 
    {
    var Age = prompt("Please enter your age here","from 4 to 100");

        if (Age >= 16) 
        {
    document.write("You are old enough to drive.");
        } 
        else if (Age >=21) 
        {
    document.write("You are old enough to drive and vote.");
        } 
        else if (Age >=65)
        {
    document.write("You are old enough to drive, vote and retire.");
        }
        else 
        {
            document.write ("thinks");
        }
}
    </script>
</head>

<body>


    <div class="classselector">

  <button type = "button" onclick="AgeCh()">Age Checker</button>

    </div>



</body>

</html>
```

I would really appreciate the help. I really lack any ideas of why the javascript doesn't work here.

Comment: a) "doesn't work" is next to no information. What do you expect? What do you see instead? b) have you checked the developer tools console for errors? what are they? c) don't use `document.write` unless you understand the side effects - i.e. it will mess you up d) `function AgeCh {` should be `function AgeCh(){` for a start

Comment: If the input age is at least 16, then all condition is "You are old enough to drive.".  You should compare by 'less than' instead of 'more than' if the order of comparison is from lower value to higher value..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `()` in AgeCh. Function should be defined like `AgeCh()`

Corrected code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Conditions</title>
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script>
        function AgeCh() 
    {
    var Age = prompt("Please enter your age here","from 4 to 100");

        if (Age >= 16) 
        {
    document.write("You are old enough to drive.");
        } 
        else if (Age >=21) 
        {
    document.write("You are old enough to drive and vote.");
        } 
        else if (Age >=65)
        {
    document.write("You are old enough to drive, vote and retire.");
        }
        else 
        {
            document.write ("thinks");
        }
}
    </script>
</head>

<body>


    <div class="classselector">

  <button type = "button" onclick="AgeCh()">Age Checker</button>

    </div>



</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be an error with defining your function. I redefined your function using the `let AgeCh = function() {}` and this seemed to get your function to work.

https://plnkr.co/edit/rHBbofiwvO55bCLDA4jg?p=preview

docs on functions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions

Answer (score 0):

yes check your function declaration is wrong
Its like

```
 function AgeCh 
  {
```

change to

```
function AgeCh()
{
```